# Vertically center text between ornaments

Tags: vertical-alignment, pgfornament

How can I vertically center the text between the two ornaments? When I put the three lines in an `\fbox` it looks almost centered but not completely.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\pgfornament[width=4cm]{88}\\
$\mathcal{SP}$\\
\pgfornament[width=4cm]{88}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: adding a `\vspace{2mm}` visually does the job if you(re in a hurry. Would like to see a clean solution too.

Answer (score 3):

A simple `\raisebox` will do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{ stackengine}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\pgfornament[width=4cm]{88}\\
\raisebox{-0.5\height}{$\mathcal{SP}$}\\
\pgfornament[width=4cm]{88}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the number 0.5, is it 50%? And what does `\height` stand for?

Comment: `\height` is the box height. And yes I lowere the box by an amount of 50% its height, so that the base line passes through the vertical centre of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I should learn to read the documentation provided with the package. The examples at the back hint towards this solution:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node at (0,1) {\pgfornament[width=4cm,anchor=north]{88}};
   \node at (0,.5) {$\mathcal{SP}$};
   \node at (0,0) {\pgfornament[width=4cm,anchor=north]{88}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```